# Mysql indexes optimization using where between ranges

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a mysql table (1,612,480) that has these rows:

```
id,
origin_zip_start
origin_zip_end
destination_zip_start
destination_zip_end
zone
```

I added index for `origin_zip_start,origin_zip_end,destination_zip_start,destination_zip_end,zone` as I thought I should add index for when I use in where statement.

---

When I try to use this query, it returns 500ms; and I can't think of a smart way for doing the scan.

```
SELECT
    `carrier`,
    `zone`,
    `service`
FROM
    `zone_charts`
WHERE (`origin_zip_start` <= 123
    AND `origin_zip_end` >= 123)
and(`destination_zip_start` <= 456
    AND `destination_zip_end` >= 456
    OR `destination_zip_start` <= 45678
    AND `destination_zip_end` >= 45678)
AND `zone` IS NOT NULL
```

Even though it used my index, it still scans 1.6m.

```
Describe: my_index   1603448    1.45    Using where
```

Is there a good way to add index in this case? I've seen bunch of smart ways to add indexes but I could not find an idea that fits mine.

---

The database table looks like this and shows first 3 digits. The destination zips sometimes contains 5 digits, that's why I use the OR statement in my query.

```
origin_zip_start: OS
origin_zip_end: OE
destination_zip_start: DS
destination_zip_end: DE

OS  |  OE  |  DS  | DE  | zone
123 | 124  | 444  | 446 | 3
125 | 126  | 444  | 446 | 5
127 | 130  | 446  | 446 | 3
```

Comment: How many rows does that query output? Of the 1.61MM rows, how many rows are not null? Perhaps you could try creating an index on zone, origin_zip_start, origin_zip_end and see if that performs better.

Comment: The other option that comes to mind is to rewrite the query like: where origin_zip_start <= 123 AND origin_zip_end >= 123 and destination_zip_start <= 123 destination_zip_end >= 123 AND zone IS NOT NULL `UNION ALL ` where origin_zip_start <= 123 AND origin_zip_end >= 123 and destination_zip_start <= 12345 destination_zip_end >= 12345 AND zone IS NOT NULL and see if that alters performance/index scan.

Comment: reduce the index to match the following (in order): zone, origin_zip_start, destination_zip_start

Comment: Think about converting your data to geometry (spatial) datatype and creating spatial index. Use, for example, (virtual) generated columns.

Comment: I wonder how a query like this would be useful?!?

Comment: I tried zedfoxus' ideas but the scan count did not change (as I don't have many null cases for `zone`). @Akina What do you mean by spatial and creating spatial index? Can you please give me an example? In the examples I found, it uses latitude & longitude and convert it to Point() but I could not figure out how to apply it to my case

Comment: *What do you mean by spatial and creating spatial index? Can you please give me an example?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html *In the examples I found, it uses latitude & longitude and convert it to Point()* Any geometry may be used (in your case you need in common linear, 1D, geometry, and Point/Line values). Coordinates are the most commonly used, but not the only thing that this type of data can be used for.

Comment: @Strawberry I have origin_zip_code and destination_zip_code and I want to query the zones for carrier services. An example would be: origin_zip_code between 12300-12399 - distination_zip_code between 45600-45899 (in db that'd be `origin_zip_start: 123, origin_zip_end: 123, destination_zip_start: 456, destination_zip_end 458`). And let's say you want to query: origin_zip: 12358, destination_zip: 45678.

Comment: This makes sense in a linear city. Otherwise I don't get it. Anyway, that's your prerogative, I guess.

Comment: @Strawberry I added an example at the end of OP. Can you please take a look? The user will enter origin_zip & destination_zip. I'll take only first 3 digits of both values and compare it to the zip codes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The Optimizer can't assume that origin_zip_start <= origin_zip_end.  If it could know that, the are lots of optimizations to consider.  Rethink the schema design.

Comment: To compare `45600` to `456`, you should use strings, not integers.

Comment: Are the start..end pairs unique?  Or do they overlap?  If they don't overlap, (or can be made not to overlap), then we may be able to take advantage of such, as in:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Comment: @RickJames They do not overlap, however i am confused with the link you've sent. Can you please explain how it would fit in the zip case?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following; if it doesn't help you answer your question, it may at least help you formulate a better one...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,origin_range_start CHAR(5)
,origin_range_end CHAR(5)
,destination_range_start CHAR(5)
,destination_range_end CHAR(5)
,zone INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(origin_range_start,origin_range_end,destination_range_start,destination_range_end)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'123','124ZZ','444','446ZZ',3),
(2,'125','126ZZ','444','446ZZ',5),
(3,'127','130ZZ','446','446ZZ',3);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------+
| id | origin_range_start | origin_range_end | destination_range_start | destination_range_end | zone |
+----+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------+
|  1 | 123                | 124ZZ            | 444                     | 446ZZ                 |    3 |
|  2 | 125                | 126ZZ            | 444                     | 446ZZ                 |    5 |
|  3 | 127                | 130ZZ            | 446                     | 446ZZ                 |    3 |
+----+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------+

SELECT id
     , zone 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE '123' BETWEEN origin_range_start AND origin_range_end
   AND '446' BETWEEN destination_range_start AND destination_range_end;   
+----+------+
| id | zone |
+----+------+
|  1 |    3 |
+----+------+

EXPLAIN
SELECT id
     , zone 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE '123' BETWEEN origin_range_start AND origin_range_end
   AND '446' BETWEEN destination_range_start AND destination_range_end\G
   
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: my_table
         type: range
possible_keys: origin_range_start
          key: origin_range_start
      key_len: 21
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition
```

Answer (score 0):

(Currently too big for a Comment; I hope to expand it into an Answer.)

Thinking out loud...

As you are finding out, "ranges" are a nuisance to optimize in `WHERE` clauses.

What if each range of zipcodes were "owned" by someone (like a "city").  Then 12340..12459 might "belong" to Anytown, Kansas.

Now, you could, very efficiently, turn 12345 into "Anytown, Kansas".  The potential advantage is that this is a single point, not a range.  This shows the equivalent problem (and solution) with IP-addresses:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Now, my understanding of your problem space gets fuzzy.  The query seems to talk about linking one city (123) with either of two others (456 or 45678).  But I am confused -- It seems that 45678 is contained within 456.

Another confusion...  Do you have multiple "carriers" that go from 123 to 456?

(Give me some more insight in your task; I may be able to carry this concept further and more efficiently.)